# FakeGGSearch.a - Lookout found a virus on my Android Phone

Tags: 2.1-eclair, antivirus

I use Android 2.1update1 and installed Lookout, and now Lookout says that: "FakeGGSearch.a" is a trojan, but I can't uninstall it!

Now what? What can I do about this? Google didn't returned any results..

Comment: Maybe post a question here: https://support.mylookout.com/forums

Comment: Can you include more details? Didn't your Lookout specify where that Trojan was found? Say, any app mentioned along where the Trojan was attached to? They don't come stand-alone: As Odysseus at Troy needed the horse to "plug in", those Trojans need an App to plug in. Probably you installed something lately, and maybe even from some, let's say, "3rd party source"?

Comment: Where are you located? This seems like it might be localized to Germany. For what it's worth, I use Lookout and nothing came up on my recent scan. (I'm using Android 4.0.4.)

Comment: I am from Romania, and I have the same message today on a HTC Hero running Android 2.1, that I didn't use in a while; I have several other devices on Android 2.2-4.1, with Lookout installed, but none gave that message.

Comment: I have had a Lookout update since this question was posted. Is this still happening? Fixing a false positive wasn't mentioned in the change log, but still...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem this morning.

Lookout reported this trojan, and it says it's part of Google Search Enhanced. When I try to uninstall I get a message saying the uninstall failed.

When I first searched for it there were no results on Google. Now there are several. So this seems to be a very new problem that people have started to see this morning.

I ran a different antivirus and it found no problems.

The phone has had no new apps installed for some time, so I'm hoping this is a false positive from Lookout.